# enter IMEI code with barcode scanner

Tags: barcode, imei

I have a problem with the creation of this function.
I would like to insert a field in the list of orders prestashop 1.5, that allows me to be filled with the bar code read by the scanner.
How can I set this up?
Thanks

http://s14.postimg.org/qbpjn03c1/Schermata_2015_09_01_alle_20_05_47.jpg